# Xamarin and OpenTK Android not starting due to TypeLoadException

Tags: android, xamarin, .net-core, nuget, opentk

I have a Xamarin Android App in Visual Studio where I would like to do some OpenGL rendering so i imported OpenTK.NETCore via nuget. Unfortunately the App wont start because of the following exception:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100003a (from typeref, class/assembly OpenTK.Rectangle, OpenTK, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bad199fe84eb3df4)
```

I have already doublechecked to have the same assemblyversion in the main project and in the android project.

the problematic line seems to be:

```
GL.Viewport(new OpenTK.Rectangle(0,0,100,100));
```